# Azure Table Storage null values in query result

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage

I am building project to store sensors data from IoT devices. I use IoT Hub, Stream Analytics and Table Storage.

I have Web API which I want to return values from Table in Table Storage. I don't know why I getting null values in response from Table Storage only in custom columns. I know that columns in Table Storage are case-sensitive and I remembered about it.

What is really interesting when I add Row to Table from .NET SDK and next query it also with SDK, I'm getting correct values (not null :) )

This is how data looks like in Storage Explorer in Azure Portal:

[image: my data in table storage]

This shows that columns have correct case-sensitive names:

[image: column names in table storage]

Here is TableValue Entity from my code:

```
public class TableValue : TableEntity
{
    public TableValue() { }

    public TableValue(string id, string deviceId)
    {
        PartitionKey = deviceId;
        RowKey = id;
    }

    public string Humidity { get; set; }
    public string Pressure { get; set; }
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
    public string SentTimestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code responsible for querying values from table storage

```
public async Task<List<TableValue>> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
            var table = _tableClient.GetTableReference("iotinsights");              
            var condition = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Develop1");
            var query = new TabyleQuery<TableValue>().Where(condition);
            var result = table.ExecuteQuery(query);

            return await Task.FromResult(result.ToList());
 }
```

Here is result I got from request in Postman:

```json
    {
        "humidity": null,
        "pressure": null,
        "temperature": null,
        "sentTimestamp": null,
        "partitionKey": "Develop1",
        "rowKey": "0131560c-d1d7-4dc3-93f0-14a4c676baa5",
        "timestamp": "2020-12-28T12:21:55.9198819+01:00",
        "eTag": "W/\"datetime'2020-12-28T11%3A21%3A55.9198819Z'\""
    },
    {
        "humidity": null,
        "pressure": null,
        "temperature": null,
        "sentTimestamp": null,
        "partitionKey": "Develop1",
        "rowKey": "022bc3f8-c8d5-4ff5-88b6-57e53c720aa9",
        "timestamp": "2020-12-28T12:27:22.9991905+01:00",
        "eTag": "W/\"datetime'2020-12-28T11%3A27%3A22.9991905Z'\""
    }, ...
```

What should I do to get correct values from this Table?

Comment: the column names in your table class are pascal casing while on the postman output the null columns are in camel casing. this could be the reason as azure table storage columns are case sensitive

Comment: I tired all casing options and it is not problem. All entities i return from api are always camel casing

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, it was easier than i thought. Custom Table Entity properties must have correct data types

```
    public class TableValue : TableEntity
{
    public TableValue() { }

    public TableValue(string id, string deviceId)
    {
        PartitionKey = deviceId;
        RowKey = id;
    }

    public Double? Humidity { get; set; }
    public Double? Pressure { get; set; }
    public Double? Temperature { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SentTimestamp { get; set; }
    
}
```